# How to add and subtract values of an argument using a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ok so I'm very new to python and coding in general so I think I need some help on this one. I will be frank, in that this is an assignment I have at the moment in which I am struggling greatly with, due to the fact that I am new to coding and all that jazz.

So the problem is I have to make this function as follows:

get_position_in_direction(position, direction) that takes a row, column pair representing the position of a square, and a direction character (one of n, s, e, w) and returns the position of the adjacent square in the given direction.
For example :

```
>>> get_position_in_direction((2,3), 'e')
(2, 4)

>>> get_position_in_direction((2,3), 's')
(3, 3)
```

If you're confused with this, picture it as coordinates on a square (3,3) and I want to move a direction n, s, e or w (I guess north, east, south or west) so with the input of which direction the coordinate will change from (3,3) to (2,3) or whatever.

The way I wanted to do this was using a dictionary such as the one below:
DIRECTIONS = {'n': (-1, 0), 's': (1, 0), 'e': (0, 1), 'w': (0, -1)} I figured this would be the simplest way of returning the values I wanted.

So yeah like I said I am new to coding and am looking for help. I do understand a lot in python so please don't feel like you are just doing my assignment for me and I'll take your answer and just not learn anything, but I would greatly appreciate some help here. Thanks.

Comment: If you're moving east, wouldn't the first value increase by one? Opposite for west. If you're moving south, wouldn't the second value decrease by one? Opposite for north

Comment: Haha yeah, you know what I mean though. 
Just a brain fart I guess, man. Starring at a computer for this long can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DIRECTIONS dictionary is a good choice. Your function could look something like this:

```
def get_position_in_direction(position, direction):
    DIRECTIONS = {'n': (-1, 0), 's': (1, 0), 'e': (0, 1), 'w': (0, -1)} 
    offset = DIRECTIONS[direction]
    return (position[0] + offset[0], position[1] + offset[1])
```

Comment: Dude, you're a life saver. I'm glad to know I was getting close ha ha. I was just about to look into using an offset or something like that.

Thanks a bunch, man.

Answer (score 1):

Mr. E's solution is pretty straightforward, and I like it.  However, I'd point out that the more conventional solution with if statements is still pretty clean and easy to follow:

```
def get_position_in_direction(position, direction):
    output = position
    if direction == 'n':
        output = (output[0] - 1, output[1])
    elif direction == 's':
        output = (output[0] + 1, output[1])
    elif direction == 'e':
        output = (output[0], output[1] + 1)
    elif direction == 'w':
        output = (output[0], output[1] - 1)

    return output
```

I think this approach, while possibly not as efficient as Mr. E's, might (depending on how you feel about it) have an edge in terms of comprehensibility, which can be a huge deal if other people have to maintain your code.

Either way it's a close call, just an alternative that skips the dictionary.

Edit:  Just to be clear, the only reason I suggest that this approach might be easier to follow is that incrementing or decrementing a single element of the position coordinate is a good cognitive analogue to moving horizontally or vertically, as opposed to having a table of values and always doing both additions.  There may be a significant speed difference between these implementations (if that matters).

Comment: Thanks for the help man, I'll have a look at both and see which works best for my situation. 

Thanks for the input though, appreciate it.

Comment: I tried this code out man and keep coming up with the same error code.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    get_position_in_direction((3,3), 'n')
   line 18, in get_position_in_direction
    output[0] -= 1
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

Comment: Hey Robert:  I apologize, that's what I get for not testing my code before posting.  The problem is that tuples are not "mutable," meaning you can't alter their elements in place.  I edited my code to make a new tuple object and assign it to the old name, and this works.

Comment: I'll also add that my idea that this might be more readable becomes less compelling due to this change.  The dictionary approach is definitely reasonable and valid, just providing an alternative!

Comment: I appreciate the import. Thanks.